# Socket connection issues

Tags: c#, memory, garbage-collection

---

My answer:

After getting annoyed, I have found a solution. The problem was indeed C# either C#'s garbage collector or C#'s multithreading, it probably thought the object was no longer needed within THAT thread, and deleted it. The solution was found as follows:

I implemented the ClientThread into the Server class, passing the Client object as a parameters, this minor change made it work. Thank you for all your responses, if anyone in the future has this problem maybe it wasn't C#'s garbage collector. But C# mutithreading OR networking must be done within the same class. I kept my client class and just made the thread object run the function within the Server class.

If anyone can figure out what my problem was, feel free to comment so I can expand my little knowledge of C#'s memory management.

Thanks again to all the people who attempted to help me in this thread.

---

Original Question

I'm a C++ programmer so I'm used to managing memory myself, and I'm really not sure how to solve this problem.

For instance in C++:

```
while(true)
{
    void* ptr = new char[1000];
}
```

This would be an obvious memory leaking program, so I need to go ahead and clean it up with:

```
delete ptr;
```

But there are cases when I want to create memory for use in a different thread and I DO NOT WANT IT DELETED AFTER THE LOOP.

```
while(true)
{
    socket.Accept(new Client());
}
//////////Client Constructor////////////
Client()
{
    clientThread.Start();
}
```

This snippet is basically what I want to do in C#, but my client connects then disconnects immediately, I'm assuming this is because at the end of the `while` loop my `new Client()` is being deleted by our favorite Garbage Collector.

So my question is, how do I get around this and make it NOT delete my object.

Many have replied saying various things about having other links to it in the code. I forgot to mention that I also save the new client in a list of clients located globally

```
List<Client> clients;



//inside loop
clients.Add(new Client(socket.Accept()));
```

---

Ok because I'm unsure if I'm missing more information here is the ACTUAL code snippet

```
// Server class
    internal Socket socket { get; set; }
    internal Thread thread { get; set; }
    internal List<Client> clients { get; set; }
    internal void Init()
    {
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        thread = new Thread(AcceptThread);
    }
    internal void Start(int port,List<Client> clients)
    {
        var ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
        this.socket.Bind(ipep);
        this.socket.Listen(10);
        this.clients = clients;

        this.thread.Start();
    }
    internal void End()
    {
        socket.Close();
        thread.Abort();
    }
    internal void AcceptThread()
    {
        int ids = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            Client client = new Client();
            client.Init(socket.Accept());
            client.clientid = ids++;
            client.Start();
            clients.Add(client);
        }
    }

// Client class
public class Client
{
    .....

    #region Base Code

    internal void Init(Socket socket)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.status = new SocketStatus();
        this.thread = new Thread(ClientThread);
        this.stream = new Stream();
    }
    internal void Start()
    {
        thread.Start();
    }
    internal void Close()
    {
        socket.Close();
        status = SocketStatus.Null;
        thread.Abort();
    }
    internal void ClientThread()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[1];
                int rec = socket.Receive(data);
                if (rec == 0)
                    throw new Exception();
                else
                    stream.write(data[0]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I thank you for all your replies.

Comment: Your first example has undefined behavior. You need to do `delete[] ptr;`.

Comment: sorry small error in the example, its not relevant to the question though. you are correct.

Comment: As an aside, I'm guessing your Client class has a finalizer (i.e. a `~Client()` method, which looks like a C++ destructor.)  It's very likely that it shouldn't have one, so I recommend reading more on IDisposable and finalization, which will help you better understand how GC fits in, as well.

Comment: Thank you for your concern, however I have removed the finalizer at my partner's request. I will look into the IDisposable to understand GC better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how it works at all. If there exists *any reference* to the instance of `Client` you created, it is not garbage-collected. This doesn't just apply to your own code, either. Therefore, if GCing is indeed the source of your issue, you never could have accessed it in the first place!

If you weren't intending to access it, you can hold on to them anyway by putting them in a `List`. However, I believe that once you actually use them in the other thread you're talking about, your problems will go away.

Comment: I believed so too until I encountered this problem, unless their is some other problem I'm not seeing, please look at the code in my edited question for me. Thank you.

Comment: @u8sand: Are you getting an exception at all? Or is the connection just closing?

Comment: I receive a 0 byte receive, which tells me that the connection has closed. No exception however. I have tried holding it before the end of the while(true) and the client held, however that is not feasible for it must continue. I believe the problem to be the fact that objects are passed by reference and the fact that the objects are deleted within the thread. I would create a list inside the accept thread but that seems like tons of extra data for no apparent reason, I don't understand why my global list doesn't work, unless it is indeed a list of references to objects that are being destroyed

Comment: @u8sand: Let me tell you up front (again) - yours is *not* a garbage collection issue, so please stop trying to blame it for everything :) If it were GC'd, you would have received an AccessViolationException or something similar instead. Now, to the issue at hand. Are you sure the server is *sending* any data? Have you done any debugging with breakpoints to check values?

Comment: This is the server. I'll look at it some more before I come back, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I've been out of the c# game for a while but I don't see anything immediately wrong there. Garbage collection shouldn't kick in until objects are actually not referenced anymore. if your `socket.Accept()` doesn't keep a reference, perhaps you could do this manually:

```
var clients = new List<Client>();

while(true)
{
    client = new Client();
    clients.Add(client);
    socket.Accept(client);
}

////////// Client Constructor ////////////

Client()
{
    clientThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: Tried to do it exactly like that and it failed as well.

Comment: @u8sand: then we need to see more code, specifically of where the loop is and what type of object clientThread is.

Comment: Yes, and I have provided it for you, please see what you can do. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx):

> If no data is available for reading, the Receive method will block until data is 
>   available, unless a time-out value was set by using
>   Socket.ReceiveTimeout. If the time-out value was exceeded, the Receive
>   call will throw a SocketException. If you are in non-blocking mode,
>   and there is no data available in the in the protocol stack buffer,
>   the Receive method will complete immediately and throw a
>   SocketException. You can use the Available property to determine if
>   data is available for reading. When Available is non-zero, retry the
>   receive operation.
>
> If you are using a connection-oriented Socket, the Receive method will
>   read as much data as is available, up to the size of the buffer. If
>   the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown
>   method, and all available data has been received, the Receive method
>   will complete immediately and return zero bytes.

This appears to be the only way to get a 0 return value from the Receive method, and *not* get an exception, so it would appear that whatever is on the other end is closing the connection.

Comment: Well then, that leaves me with no clue as to what the problem is.
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector only deletes resources that aren't reachable through any reference in your program.  As long as you still have a variable that refers to the object, it'll continue to exist.

Comment: Yet it does not, I've tried to hold it with the debugger as well, it exists until the loop is repeated, as well as my client, it remains connected until i resume the debugger, when it disconnects because of the deletion of the socket object.

Comment: When you write `socket.Accept(new Client());`, you're not holding the client in a variable, so it becomes garbage as soon as the statement finishes.  You need to store a reference to the `Client` somewhere — presumably the thread needs access to it anyway, for communicating with the remote host.